# Java regex replace multiple file paths in a large String

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, html-parsing

So a Regex pro I am not, and I'm looking for a good way to do this.  I have a large string which contains a variable number `<img>` tags.  I need to change the path on all of these images to `images/`.  The large string also contains other stuff not just these img's.

```
<img src='http://server.com/stuff1/img1.jpg' />
<img src='http://server.com/stuff2/img2.png' />
```

Replacing the server name with a `ReplaceAll()` I could do, it's the variable path in the middle I'm clueless on how to include.  It doesn't necessarily need to be a regex, but looping through the entire string just seems wasteful.

Comment: What is the end result you expect?  It is a little unclear what you mean by replace the path with `images/`, do you just want `<img src='images/img1.jpg' />` and `<img src='images/img2.jpg' />`?

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  The file name should remain it's the variable path that needs to change.  images/img1.jpg   images/img2.jpg.  All paths should point to the images/ dir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work for replacing all `<img>` tags that link to a jpg from server.com:

```
s.replaceAll("<img src='http://server.com[^']*/([^']*)' />", "<img src='images/$1' />");
```

If you are using double quotes around the `src` property:

```
s.replaceAll("<img src=\"http://server.com[^\"]*/([^\"]*)\" />", "<img src=\"images/$1\" />");
```

This works because `[^']*/` will match as many characters that are not single quotes as possible, and then a literal '/', so it will consume the entire path.  If all `<img>` tags are from server.com you can remove `http://server.com` and the regex will work the same way.

Note that you can shorten this even more if you know in advance that all of the image tags need to be replaced, or if your string only consists of `<img>` tags, for example you could use the following to just replace the path in all `src` properties:

```
s.replaceAll("src='[^']*/([^']*)'", "src='images/$1'");
```

Just add more of the literal strings you want to match to the regex if this replaces more than you want.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't look like this is working.  It's only replacing the last <img> tag the rest are all completely removed from the string.  I think it's replacing all instances with the 1 string.

Comment: Do you use single quotes for all of the `src` properties?

Comment: no, they are double quotes actually.  Had to modify your code a little.

Comment: Just edited my answer to include an alternative for double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Commons Lang provides API to do all sorts of replaces:

```
String dirName = "images";
StringUtils.replace(html, "http://server.com/stuff1/", dirName + "/");
```

Comment: This is cool, but the stuff1/ directory is variable and may be anything.  I need a way to include and change a directory which is variable

Comment: Then put variable as a third argument: `StringUtils.replace(html, "http://server.com/stuff1/", dirName + "/");`

Answer (score 0):

Use Java String method `replaceAll(regex, replacement)`

Where

```
String regex = "(http://server\\.com/)[^<]+(/[^<]+)";
```

and

```
String directory = "images";
String replacement = "$1" + directory + "$2";
```

This will turn

```
http://server.com/stuff1/img1.jpg
```

into

```
http://server.com/images/img1.jpg
```

For example:

```
String content = "<img src=\"http://server.com/stuff1/img1.jpg\"><img src=\"http://server.com/stuff1/img2.jpg\"><img src=\"http://server.com/stuff1/img3.jpg\">"
String regex = "(http://server\\.com/).+(/img1\\.jpg)";
String directory = "images";
String replacement = "$1" + directory + "$2";
content = content.replaceAll(regex, replacement);
System.out.println(content);
```

Will output:

```
<img src="http://server.com/images/img1.jpg"><img src="http://server.com/images/img2.jpg"><img src="http://server.com/images/img3.jpg">
```

If you want to skip the full hostname and use a relative path change `replacement` into:

```
String replacement = directory + "$2";
```

This will turn

```
http://server.com/stuff1/img1.jpg
```

into

```
images/img1.jpg
```